# Steps to run metro (JAX-WS) on Websphere 6.1

Tags: websphere, jax-ws, websphere-6.1

Anyone knows the steps to run JAX-WS on Websphere 6.1? JAX-WS website doesn't lists any step. Though other frameworks like Apache cxf do list the steps to configure on Websphere 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal way is to use the free, supported [WebSphere Feature Pack for Web Services](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264563). Although regrettably, this requires you to create a new Profile in WebSphere. But it provides integrated, supported JAX-WS capability without needing additional libraries.

Are you asking about using a specific JAX-WS implementation? Like the Reference Implementation? If so, is there a particular reason you need to use that one?

Comment: That Websphere internally uses an Axis2 runtime. Surely he prefers the Reference Implementation.

Comment: True, and possibly. Certainly worth asking.